# Django infinite scroll messed up design. CSS need correction

Tags: django

I am developing one website using Django. The website link is,
http://flooroof.com/listings/

You can see that the tiles on the website has got overlap on each other. This happened after I implemented infinite scroll. I found it at below link,
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/03/13/how-to-create-infinite-scroll-with-django.html

If you scroll down you will see more and more properties are getting loaded. At a time I am loading 20 listings. But not sure what has gone wrong.

I know there is something wrong with CSS but I am not sure what it is.

Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as I can see the CSS has issue especially in .grid-item present on after first .infinite-item. I .grid-item has absolute position and only first .infinite-item's .grid-item has proper left and top values. If you want a quick solution then you can do this.

```
a.grid-item
{
    left: auto !important;
    top: auto !important;
    position: relative !important;
}
```

One more issue is with image size. your images size are very different from each other so best solution is to use a blank 1px trasparent image with fixed height and show current images as background image.

Comment: The quick solution did not work. The image size is actually giving better look to the website because design is similar to offerup.com. So different image sizes arrange it in different way. If you cannot open that website try to use proxy server. offerup is US only website.